# trying to keep image locked into the area of another image

Tags: html, css

I have a function that expands a image full screen, I'm trying to get a close button to always be contained in the upper right of the bigger image. (top: 5px left: 5px

```
<div id="full_image"><img src="" /><span>
<a href="#" class="close_full" ></a></span>
```

the Css

```
#full_image {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 9;
}

#full_image img {
left: 10px;
width: 339px;
height: 211px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.close_full {
background: url("off.png") no-repeat scroll right top transparent;
cursor: pointer;
height: 29px;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
margin-top: -36px;
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
width: 29px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

my jquery

```
$('.zoom_big').click(function () {
if (current === 0)
$('#full_image img').attr("src", get_org_images[0]);
$('#full_image img').attr("src", get_org_images[current]);

    $('#bg')
        .css("z-index", "6")
        .animate({opacity: 1}, '1500', function () {      
            $('#full_image').css("z-index", "900");
            $('#full_image').css("opacity", "1");
            var w = $(window);
            var sr = w.height() / w.width();

            var i = $('#full_image img').css({
                'width': 'auto',
                'height': 'auto'
            });
            var ir = i.height() / i.width();

            if (sr < ir) i.css('height', w.height());
            else i.css('width', w.width());


            var wd = Math.abs(i.width() - w.width());
            var hd = Math.abs(i.height() - w.height());
            if (wd != 0) {i.css('left', wd / 2);}
            // if (hd != 0) { i.css('top',hd / 2); }  
        });
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What are you asking?

Comment: I always want .close_full to be contained within full image

Comment: and what are you experiencing now? what exactly is your js function doing? can you provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2M6KA/15/  If i move the woz image say 10 to the right I want the other image to be forced to move with it

Comment: I would need to see your jQuery code otherwise i'm going to have the same problem as everyone else. That is produce an example then you say you can't use it for some reason.